# Cannot reproduce Etherscan verified compilation for 0.6.6 contract

Tags: solidity, etherscan, solc, optimization, immutable

I'm trying to reproduce the following contract compilation on Etherscan: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#code.

---

**Runtime bytecode on-chain**

I can get the runtime bytecode on chain by calling `eth_getCode` for the contract address from a JSON RPC client connected to mainnet.

Here is the bytecode I get:

```
60806040526004361061018f5760003560e01c80638803dbee116100d6578063c45a01551161007f578063e8e3370011610059578063e8e3370014610c71578063f305d71914610cfe578063fb3bdb4114...
```

---

**Runtime bytecode (Etherscan)**

Here, looking at the etherscan contract information in the link above, I notice 3 key things: compiler version (`0.6.6`), optimisation runs (999999) and evm version (istanbul).

So I set up Solidity compilation as follows:

```json
{
    "language": "Solidity",
    "sources":
    {
        "uniswap.sol":
        {
            "urls":
            [
                "./uniswap.sol"
            ]
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "optimizer": {
            "runs": 999999
        },
        "evmVersion": "istanbul",
        "outputSelection": {
            "*": {
                "*": [ "evm.deployedBytecode" ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and ran with:

```
solc --standard-json --allow-paths .
```

But I'm getting slightly different bytecode:

```
60806040526004361061018f5760003560e01c80638803dbee116100d6578063c45a01551161007f578063e8e3370011610059578063e8e337001461131e578063f305d71914611406578063fb3bdb4114...
```

What could be wrong in the reproduction and how may I amend it? Can constructor arguments change runtime bytecode if immutable values are used?

Comment: Did you check it with [Bytecode Verifier](https://github.com/ConsenSys/bytecode-verifier) by Consensys, also this article [Verify Ethereum Contracts Using Web3.js and Solc](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/ethereum/verify-ethereum-contracts-using-web3-js-and-solc/) may help understand what may be wrong.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for sharing the article! From what I understand, the verifier is out of date. I've gone through all the steps in the article and have not diverged from them - unfortunately I'm getting the same outcome.

Comment: Did you enable the optimizer `"enabled": true`?

Comment: Possibly related: the optimizer has changed in v0.6.12.

Comment: @Ismael - amazing, that was it. There are now only about ~100 characters that are different in the respective constructor bytecodes after removing constructor arguments.

Comment: Feel free to submit a  response and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some comments we found the optimizer wasn't enabled

The setting for the optimizer has to be modified to add a `"enabled"`, so it look like this:

```
"settings": {
    "optimizer": {
        "enabled": true,
        "runs": 999999
    },
    ....
}
```